# 'tensorflow_federated.python.simulation' has no attribute 'FromTensorSlicesClientData' when using tff-nightly

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I was using `tff.simulation.FromTensorSlicesClientData(client_train_dataset)` to create client's data with the stable version of tff, and it was working fine. I had to switch to tff-nightly, and now calling this gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.simulation' has no attribute 'FromTensorSlicesClientData'
```

Here's the section of my code, where the error is thrown:

```
total_clients = 3
total_samples = len(x_train)
samples_per_set = int(np.floor(total_samples/total_clients))

client_train_dataset = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in range(1, total_clients+1):
  client_name = "client_" + str(i)
  start = samples_per_set * (i-1)
  end = samples_per_set * i
  data = collections.OrderedDict((('y', y_train[start:end]), ('x', x_train[start:end])))
  client_train_dataset[client_name] = data

train_dataset = tff.simulation.FromTensorSlicesClientData(client_train_dataset)
```

Should I be doing this a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tff.simulation.TensorSlicesClientData` was renamed to [`tff.simulation.datasets.TestClientData`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/TestClientData) in commit [#1def433](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/1def433a064e251a0bd6fbf32aeb61feb97ee87a). This included in the nightly release already and will be included in the next numbered release.